# Looping in BizTalk

Tags: oracle, biztalk

On an Oracle database I got a customer table with at Id and Name and so, and a number of customerstuff tables all related a key.
With the Oracle WCF adapter in BizTalk a need to create a file with all the customers and there stuff
Like this:

```
<Root>
  <Customers>
    <Customer>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>A</Name>
      <Stuff1>
        <data>
         .
         .
        </data>
      </Stuff1>
      .
      .
      <Stuff6>
        <data>
        .
        .
        </data>
      </Stuff6>
   </Customer>
   <Customer>
     <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>B</Name>
      <Stuff1>
      .
      .
      .
      </Stuff6>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</Root>
```

I started out with a select of all the customers, and in Orchestration I loop over them, selecting from each customerstuff table with the key from the current customer getting me all the data ready for the first customer node in the result file.

**Question:** how do I build the result file?   I have to add the current customer/customerstuff data to the result file, then do a new loop while still holding on to the result file, how can I do that in BizTalk ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with custom XSLT, but I am unsure without seeing more detail about the input and output schemas.

If you go with the looping approach, this is going to require 3 messages

- Output Message (your eventual output)
- Current Output Placeholder Message (same schema as your eventual output)
- Customer Stuff (the data you want to Append to output on a given pass through the loop)

  and a map that has two messages to one (or some XPATH based manipulation):

For Each Customer

- Create "Customer Stuff"
- Copy Output Message to Current Output Placeholder
- Perform Map that takes Customer Stuff and Current Output Placeholder Message as input and maps to the "Output Message"

Comment: That is what I 'm trying to do, but the "•Copy Output Message to Current Output Placeholder" has to been done in a ConstructMessage shape wish is creating a new Output Message, losing the previous version, or am I missing something?

Comment: Its okay to lose the output message because have to reconstruct the message in the third step

Answer (score 0):

Try using something similar to "for xml" in sql server, when you read the data itself using query or stored procedure. In oracle you can return the result set as xml using dbms_xmlgen package:

select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from emp where rownum <= 2') xmlstr from dual;

Comment: It should work, create a stored procedure with this query and use that stored procedure to generate schemas.